# SSIS 4000 Character Limitation Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

My SSIS package needs to read JSON files and store the entire JSON text into a single row. Currently, I can do this no problem with a flat file source.

However, the data type must be DT_NTEXT so I can import more than 4000 characters. 
My issue arises when I need to include more data captured from the filename and directory path. Once it passes through a script component to capture that information, I can no longer write the JSON data back into its original column DT_NTEXT is read only. I have also tried just reading the files from Script Component and run into the same issue.

I also tried using them as two different data sources and merging them, but the data type will not allow me to sort. Lastly, I have tried to assign the JSON data to a variable using the script component, but you can only do this in post execute.

The irony of the whole situation is that all the data only needs to be on a single row for each file. The columns are outlined here:

[image: Current Script output]

Here is a picture of my current dataflow, but this doesn't reflect everything I have tried.

[image: Control flow]

[image: Data flow]

If anyone can help me with these bizarre limitations it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL? There are new JSON functions. Can you do it with a sproc and a script task?

Comment: Using 2016. I know it has OPENJSON, which is why I am putting the entire JSON data into a row, so I can use that command in a trigger on import. Seems to work pretty well, but I need the extra information from the filename.

Comment: I don't really get it. But if you wanted to do script magic in a dataflow that results in a column - a **script transformation** is a waay better idea than variable + script component

Comment: I've tried this method, but I keep getting stuck at the 4000 character limit after trying to reassign the json data to an output0buffer column. If i do it in the post execute to the variable, its not assigned until after the dataflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your script component, convert the JSON string to a byte array and store it.

```
string jsonData = "<Your json string>";
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
OutputBuffer.AddRow(); 
OutputBuffer.JSON.AddBlobData(encoding.GetBytes(jsonData ));
```

Follow this link for further details.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5047/import-and-export-varcharmax-data-with-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/

Comment: This looks very promising. Will try tomorrow and confirm.

Comment: Seems to be on the right track, but now my data is outputting to broken Chinese characters. Example: ൻ †∠䭓≕›㠢㌳〱ⴵ㉂∱‬਍††匢慴畴≳›ൻ †††∠效污桴㨢∠䭏ഢ †素‬਍††吢灹≥›䌢浯異整卲獹. This only happening for the JSON column

Comment: Solved. Needed to output to DT_Text first, then convert to DT_NText